# How to remove soap 1.2 from WSDL

Tags: soap-api, webservices, soap, wsdl

I want to use a WSDL in order to retrieve data from our BI's system. However, the WSDL contains two services: soap1.1 and soap1.2 Our system does not work with WSDL that contains more than one service and specifically not supports soap1.2. Therefore, I want to remove soap1.2 service from the WSDL. Is there any online tool for doing that? if not, I could not find a good guide for manually split.

```
<wsdl:service name="CommandWebService">
   <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">A webservice which
         performs provisioning and execution for Birst</wsdl:documentation>
   <wsdl:port name="CommandWebServiceSoap" binding="tns:CommandWebServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://app2101.eu1.birst.com/commandwebservice.asmx" />
   </wsdl:port>
   <wsdl:port name="CommandWebServiceSoap12" binding="tns:CommandWebServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://app2101.eu1.birst.com/commandwebservice.asmx" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: I have had success with simply removing the wsdl:port section and IIRC there may have been a one other places where where soap12 is mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool you can use to do this. It's the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclosure, this is a free tool from my current employer).

It contains an independent version of the WSDL2Apex tool to generate the Apex. In this version it will ignore the SOAP 1.2 portions and just work with what is supported. Basically anything in the soap12 namespace.

There are expanded details in my Dreamforce 2014 presentation - [Improved Apex support for SOAP based web services](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html).